# Nodejs Callback async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

```
  users = [];
  .on('result', function(user) {
          async.waterfall([
              function(cb) {
                  get_comm(user.post_id, function(comms) {

                      user.comm = comms;
                      users.push(user);
                      cb(users);
                  })
              },
          ], function(users, cb) {

              console.log(users); // it prints out
          });

      })
      .on('end', function() {
          if (connectionsArray.length) {
              pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
              updateSockets({
                  users: users // empty []; !!

              });

          }
      });
```

So I want after finishing on result loop to print out all data but array is full in result loop and empty out of it.

Comment: var get_comm = function (post_id , cb){varcomments=connection.query(..); comments.on('end', function() {
cb(comms);})}

users =[] ;
var query = connection.query(...);
.on('result', function(user) {
async.waterfall([
function(cb){get_comm(user.post_id , function(comms){

    user.comm = comms;
    users.push(user);
    cb(users);
})
},
],function(users ,cb){

    console.log(users); // it prints out
});

   })
 .on('end', function() {
  if (connectionsArray.length) {
pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
 updateSockets({
  users: users // empty []; !!

   });

      }
  });

Comment: here it is teh full code check it out @jfriend00

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `on` method is from an instance of a [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener). If so the callbacks passed to `on` aren't async capable.

You're code is doing async within them.